# New row in one field for CSV writing

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I haven't worked that much with csv export, and now I have a problem. I have something like this:

```
['client']=>
  ['name']=>'John',
  ['surname']=>'Doe',
  ['things']=>
    [0]=>'jacket',
    [1]=>'shoes',
    [2]=>'hat'
```

And when I parse ti for csv I get

```
name | surname | things
John | Doe     | jacket, shoes, hat
```

And I would like to get

```
name | surname | things
John | Doe     | jacket
                 shoes
                 hat
```

Is there a way to do it in PHP?

EDIT: I tried this:

```
$client['things'] = ",".implode(",", $client['things']);
```

I tried this also

```
$client['things'] = ",".implode("\n", $client['things']);
```

and this

```
$client['things'] = ",".implode("\r", $client['things']);
```

and it didn't worked properly.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? You want newlines instead of commas?

Comment: It's possible to write in PHP. Read sth about arrays and implode

Comment: Try using PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), it'll make your life much easier... and it'll ensure that your values are wrapped in quotes, so that embedded "\" within a field will be parsed correctly by many csv readers

Comment: @JayBlanchard I want new row but in a same field... if possible

Comment: Here's a hint: you want 3 different CSV rows written, so you need 3 different arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV doesn't support nested sets of values.

Also according with [RFC for CSV format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt):

> Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF).

and

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes.

You must exlude unescaped new line separators, commas and quote symbols and I suggest you to use [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to generate valid and correct CSV for most programs and libraries.

E.g.:

```php
<?php
$row = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'surname' => 'Doe',
    'things' => array('jacket', 'shoes', 'hat'),
);
$row = array_map(function ($value) {
    return is_array($value) ? implode(',', $value) : $value;
}, $row);
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Outputs: `John,Doe,"jacket,shoes,hat"` with CRLF ending.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Thank you all for your answers. :)